# Amount of EXCEL records batch transferred to MySQL in VBA

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, variables

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYLm6.jpg)I am writing a VBA code wanna update csv records to computer memory until 100 entries for a batch then insert into MySQL database to enhance 49776 records transfer efficiency rather than record by record.

Having used F8 to peform my code line by line that learned variables could not get value from excel record as below then go to designated on-error "Tran_Err" process. Don't know how to fix it.

```vb
        myRS![tDate] = Cells(myRow, 1).Value
        myRS![secID] = Cells(myRow, 2).Value
        myRS![grade] = Cells(myRow, 3).Value
        myRS![ppl] = Cells(myRow, 4).Value
        myRS![shares] = Cells(myRow, 5).Value
        myRS![percentage] = Cells(myRow, 6).Value
```

All your kindly help will be highly appreciated. My code is:

```vb
    Sub addALL()
    Dim myCon As ADODB.Connection
    Dim myRS As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim myRow As Long, myTmpRow As Long
    
    'connection setup
    Set myCon = New ADODB.Connection
    
    myCon.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};" & _
               "Server=localhost;" & _
               "Database=tdcc;" & _
               "User=root;" & _
               "Password=root;" & _
               "Option=3;"
    'database setup
    Set myRS = New ADODB.Recordset
    myRS.Open "tdcc", myCon, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
    myRow = 2
    On Error GoTo Tran_Err
    'begins to add
    myCon.BeginTrans
    'loop until column A is null
    Do Until Cells(myRow, 1).Value = ""
        'add record
        myRS.AddNew        
        myRS![tDate] = Cells(myRow, 1).Value
        myRS![secID] = Cells(myRow, 2).Value
        myRS![grade] = Cells(myRow, 3).Value
        myRS![ppl] = Cells(myRow, 4).Value
        myRS![shares] = Cells(myRow, 5).Value
        myRS![percentage] = Cells(myRow, 6).Value 
      
        'update here, yet to append to database
        myRS.Update
        myRow = myRow + 1
        'append to database for 100 entries
        If myRow Mod 100 = 3 Then
            myCon.CommitTrans
            myCon.BeginTrans
        End If
    Loop
    'append to database for the residual records
    myCon.CommitTrans
    
    'clearance of events
    myRS.Close
    Set myRS = Nothing
    myCon.Close
    Set myCon = Nothing
    MsgBox myRow - 2 & " records has been well appended"
    Exit Sub
    
Tran_Err:
    'put into litter of incorrect update
    myCon.RollbackTrans
    'move to error record position
    Application.Goto Rows(myRow), True
    myTmpRow = Int((myRow - 2) / 100) * 100
    MsgBox "Record # " & myRow & " error happens, " & myTmpRow & " records has been appended"
    Set myRS = Nothing
    myCon.Close
    Set myCon = Nothing
End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iDwM.jpg)

Comment: Don't you want `UpdateBatch` instead of `Update`?

Comment: Thanks for your input, having made a try Update instead UpdateBatch and not work. Seems my problem comes from variable setting like myRS![tDate]= Cells(myRow, 1).value statement unable to get data from EXCEL record.

Comment: Is there a date in the source cell ?

Comment: Again, nope, the source cell of cells(myRow,1) is 20210326, guess it should be a string. Thanks for your hands.

Comment: Should add an error message for reference: error code is 6, "Overflow", at statement myRS![tDate]= Cells(myRow, 1), cells(myrow,1) should be 20210326. Thanks

Comment: case closed. having modified the column format from date to varchar(45). everything goes fine. thanks all.

Comment: An alternative would be to keep date type in table and parse the string with a function like `Function ymd(s) As Date: ymd = DateSerial(Left(s, 4), Mid(s, 5, 2), Right(s, 2)): End Function`

Comment: Thanks for your input as well. I do really hope there is a way of transfer EXCEL number to MySQL without parse.

Comment: You only parse once on input `myRS![tDate] = ymd(Cells(myRow, 1).Value)` Then you can use mysql Date/Time function as normal.